# Locating Elements with dynamic id

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, salesforce

If you have an element in a page as follows (there are multiple select elements)

```
<select size="1" name="j_id0:j_id2:j_id37:j_id38:0:j_id41">
<select size="1" name="j_id0:j_id2:j_id37:j_id38:1:j_id41">
```

With the only identifier being its name but the name will change dynamically how would you locate it in selenium(java) without referencing the name?

I am currently using the xpath as follows

```
/html/body/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/form/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/span[3]/select
```

Problem being if anything on the page changes this xpath will be break.

Are there any better alternative ways which are less easily broken?

Comment: Do you use JSF 2.x? If so, you could actually add `id`s to your forms and form elements to avoid them from getting auto generated. Almost every other selector you're planning to use is likely to be more brittle than the `id`.

Comment: Is there a parent element that has a more unique name? In that way, you may be able to limit the area that needs to change before the xpath would break.

Comment: Just a div with a similar auto-generating id

Comment: Can you provide more of the html structure. Sure that all the divs do not have a unique id or a name? Maybe it's just the select element that has a dynamic name? (see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

You've correctly noted that the presented XPath is quite fragile. It would be also useful to see the complete HTML of the page, or, at least, preceding and following elements of the `select` element. From what we have now, you can rely on the part of the `name` attribute:

```
//select[contains(@name, "j_id")]
```

Comment: There are unfortunately multiple elements on the page following the same naming convnetion.

Comment: @user3556152 yup, that's why I noted about seeing the HTML source of the page. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose not all ids on your site are dynamic.

So there is definitely a cleaner way to write your locator.

Provide some more of your html structure and I can give you more details.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try.. These select tags must have some labels associated. Use following-siblings and ancestor xpath axis to locate  your element relative to the labels.

http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp